# How do I pass values from one class to another; each running potentially on different threads?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a file called `filterspecs.py` that contains 3 things:

1. `tls = threading.local()`
2. class A which inherits from `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList`
3. class B which inherits from `django.contrib.admin.filterspecs.FilterSpec`

**Goal**: I want to pass a value, a `list`, available to an instance of `A` to an instance of `B`. Since the lifecycle of A and B are managed by the framework (Django), I cannot think of private way to pass the data between the instances (Using a `Queue` would be an overkill).

**Attempt #1** fails when using WSGI (daemon) mode.
In class A, the list is added to the threadlocal.

```
1.    tls.list_display = ['foo', 'bar']
```

But in class B, the following returns `False`:

```
2.    hasattr(tls, 'list_display')
```

Just for comparison sake, this works outside of apache/mod_wsgi if I run it via

```
manage.py runserver
```

I looked at the logs and discovered that different threads were executing lines 1 & 2.

What other ways can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I can't understand what this has to do with threads (there's very little use of threads inside Django, and none in the admin). Please can you explain exactly what you're trying to do - in what context are you using these classes, and why are you passing data between them?

Comment: I am not using threads in my code at all. Basically every time a new ``ChangeList`` is created, it filters the queryset using my ``FilterSpec``. ChangeList knows about the ModelAdmin which contains ``list_display`` & I need inside my FilterSpec. If there's a simple python way for me to share that value with FilterSpec ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to share data between not just two classes, but between two completely different HTTP requests.  HTTP is stateless -- Apache is not designed to accommodate stateful web applications.  You must save the data to a database and read it back in the second request.  (Or you can run your web application in a separate process and manage the state yourself -- which essentially adds "database programmer" to your job description.  This is not recommended.)

Your two pieces of code might not just be running in different threads, they might be running in different *processes.*

Comment: I just double checked. They are running with the same process id, but different thread ids.

Comment: @Bon Ami: It is unusual for an Apache server to run as a single process.  This is a combination of luck, testing with only one client, and HTTP keepalive.  There is no good way to guarantee that the same Apache process will handle both requests.

Comment: The two threads that are running are not a result of 2 calls. I clicked on a link (that sorts the data), which in turn caused this behavior. Note that I am not starting any threads. The life-cycle of both class *A* and *B* are managed by Django.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "call".  Are they both objects created to handle the same HTTP request?

Comment: By *call*, I mean one HTTP GET or POST request. Yes.

Comment: In that case, using globals such as TLS is going to cause different requests to collide.  Try attaching extra data to the request object.